# Laravel 5.1 not loading images (always pending)

Tags: laravel-5.1

All of my images are in public/images folder. I had no problem. Suddenly my images (background images & `img` elements) not loading (always pending). 
could anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

Image source: *public/images/image.png*

Css source: *public/css/style.css*

**Inline:**

```
<div style="height: 45px;background-image:url('{{ asset('images/image.png') }}');border-radius: 5px;position:relative">
```

**In css file:**

```
background-image: url("../images/image.png")
```

**Img src with asset in blade:**

```
<img src="{{asset('images/image.png')}}" alt="">
```

Comment: background images defined in style.css file.

Comment: what is the "pending" image url? (in chrome right click, and open image in new tab)

Comment: for example: http://mysite.dev/images/image.png it shows my image. but <img src="http://mysite.dev/images/image.png" alt="" > not works!

Comment: Try: `<img src="{{asset('images/image.png')}}" alt="">`